# postgresql - is it possible to run different SELECT functions based on a filter?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql function that collects data (data is the same) from tree different postgresql functions. But, it should be possible to only run some of the three functions based on a filter. Example

```
FROM (SELECT events.id,
            events.slug,
            events.picture_url,
            events.lat,
            events.lng,
            events.user_id,
            events.inserted_at,
            events.updated_at,
            events.geom,
            events.address,
            events.place
            FROM (
              -- DO FILTERING CASE WHEN (filter = 'global' OR filter = 'self') THEN
                  SELECT * from my_events(param_user_id)
              END
              UNION
              -- DO FILTERING CASE WHEN (filter = 'global' OR filter = 'friends') THEN
                --by starting from follows table
                SELECT * FROM follows(param_user_id)
              END
              UNION
              -- DO FILTERING CASE WHEN (filter = 'global' OR filter = 'friends') THEN
                SELECT * FROM friends_events(param_user_id)
              END

            ) AS events ORDER BY events.inserted_at DESC LIMIT limit_count OFFSET limit_count * page
          ) AS e;  END; $function$
```

A filter is a text string for example filter = "function 1". 
If filter = "function 1" then only execute SELECT  and ignore the other two.

```
If filter = "all" then run all of them. Lambda example
SELECT (<fields>) FROM(
IF filter = "function1" OR filter = "all" then
SELECT <function 1>
IF filter = "function 2" OR filter = "all" THEN

SELECT <function2>
```

And so on.

Comment: i read `$function$` in your PostgreSQL SQL code. So i assume your question is about PostgreSQL's PL/pgSQL.. in PL/pgSQL it's possible to use conditional flow control.. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html section **39.6.2. Conditionals**

Answer (score 0):

You can use standalone IF on manner:

```
IF filter = 'func1' THEN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT ...;
ELSEIF filter = 'func2' THEN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT ...;
ELSEIF
  ...
END IF;
```

---

Or, better, dynamic query to not duplicate big SELECT:

```
DECLARE
  _str text;
BEGIN
  ...
  --Build dynamic query:
  _str = 'SELECT ... FROM '||filter||'('||param_user_id||') ...';
  --Print to console (Use to debug only)
  RAISE NOTICE '_str = %', _str;
  --Execute and return results
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _str;
  ...
END
```

Here text from `filter` is concatenated with the query and used as name of function. If you can't put name of function in `filter`, use

```
CASE filter WHEN 'func1' THEN 'name_of_func1' WHEN 'func2' THEN 'name_of_func2' ... ELSE 'name_of_default_func' END
```

in concatenation instead of `filter` itself.

---

Use that way which will be more readable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can modify your query and some variable to choose which funciotn you want to run.

```
CREATE FUNCTION a1() RETURNS TABLE (t text, k text) AS $f$
       SELECT f1, f2 FROM t1;
$f$ LANGUAGE sql;


EXPLAIN ANALYZE
 SELECT * FROM a1() WHERE true
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM a2() WHERE false
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM a3() WHERE false;
                                              QUERY PLAN                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Append  (cost=0.25..20.25 rows=1000 width=64) (actual time=0.677..0.865 rows=291 loops=1)
   ->  Function Scan on a1  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=64) (actual time=0.676..0.758 rows=291 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.222 ms
 Execution time: 0.981 ms
```

You can call all three functions together:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
 SELECT * FROM a1() WHERE true
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM a2() WHERE true
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM a3() WHERE true ;
                                              QUERY PLAN                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Append  (cost=0.25..60.75 rows=3000 width=64) (actual time=0.682..2.324 rows=873 loops=1)
   ->  Function Scan on a1  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=64) (actual time=0.681..0.770 rows=291 loops=1)
   ->  Function Scan on a2  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=64) (actual time=0.512..0.599 rows=291 loops=1)
   ->  Function Scan on a3  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=64) (actual time=0.557..0.644 rows=291 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.227 ms
 Execution time: 2.615 ms
```

Or none of all:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
 SELECT * FROM a1() WHERE false
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM a2() WHERE false
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM a4() WHERE false ;
                                 QUERY PLAN                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=64) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
   One-Time Filter: false
 Planning time: 0.191 ms
 Execution time: 0.036 ms
```